# Screen not moving up after keyboard appears when user clicks on a text field inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard

I have an iPhone application where the content dynamically loads a form from a CMS. The form contains fields where a user needs to enter and submit, nothing tricky.

Unfortunately, when the user clicks on the form, the keyboard appears and it is hiding the `UIWebView` that is containing the form.

How am I able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

My only solution at the moment is a hack:

At the end of the form tag, I simply added a dozen of non-breakable-space tags
This allows the UIWebview to scroll up hence showing the textbox to the user above the keyboard.